# Cocos Nucifera big brown spot

Tags: leaves

I have bought a coconut tree half a year ago from ikea. everything was going well, one time it had some kind of small pests (maybe spider mites) - i washed the leaves, sprayed it with water everyday and it seemed that the problem was gone. Just recently i have discovered that the smaller leaves had those too, did the same thing. Now a big brown spot has emerged on my biggest leaf, and i think its growing. I have searched all over google, but could not find any results, so i decided to ask on this forum.

[image: the coconut yesterday][image: the coconut today]